# How to find the number of common characters of two input strings in Assembly?

Tags: string, algorithm, assembly

I need to compare two input strings and display the number of common characters in Assembly but i can't find how to do that.

Comment: 1. What have you tried so far? StackOverflow is not a "do my homework" site.

2. Which architecture are you writing assembly code for?

Comment: How would you do in a high level language? The basic algorithm won't change between it and assembly. It's not clear exactly what you are asking.

Comment: When I want to count the number of common characters in assembly, I generally write some code. :)

Answer (score 1):

To do it efficiently you would need some sort of data structure to remember which characters you have seen already.

If you don’t mind duplicates and don't need efficiency, you could loop over the first string and, for each character, loop over the second string and compare them (adding one to a register or a variable when they match).

Comment: For ASCII, a 256-entry present/absent array is easy to create from one string, then check for each char of the other.  To dedup, set the presence entry back to zero after printing.  Fun little algorithm-design problem.  The actual implementation in asm is straightforward, and to me not the interesting part of this question at all.  It's nice that you only need the number of common chars, not to print them at all, let alone in any kind of order.  I almost want to answer it too, even thought it's a horrible question and we shouldn't reward lazy "do my homework" questions.

Comment: ASCII is easy, Unicode (either UTF-8, 16 or 32) is not as simple unless you use vast amount of memory. Also, to find the right algorithm, you need to state the problem precisely i.e. know the output of a given input before you write the code à la TDD. So if you compare ABBA with BABA, do you expect 2 (A&B), 4 (first A twice, first B twice) or 8 (2*2+2*2)?

Comment: Great point about whether duplicates count, hadn't thought of that.

Comment: Homework assignments to do anything with characters in asm are always talking about ASCII bytes.  Even with vast amounts of memory, just decoding a variable-length encoding like UTF-8 (or UTF-16 now that unicode has outgrown 16-bit) would be significantly complex.  But yes, with UTF-32 it would be this easy, at least on a 64-bit system where you can easily have a 4G array.

Comment: Assuming it's ASCII and you want to ignore duplicates, I would use two 256 bits words, parse the first string and set the first word's bits to 1 for each character found. I would do the same for the second word and the second string then do a binary AND between the two words.

Comment: How would you manage the 256b bitmap, though?  You need to be able to efficiently set an arbitrary bit, so keeping it in an AVX2 register doesn't work well.  Keeping it in multiple integer registers requires a branching implementation.  Keeping it in memory means that there's a store/reload round-trip latency between most characters, even if you use single-byte loads/stores.  Setting a single bit takes a read-modify-write, not just a write of a byte.

Comment: A common histogram technique is to unroll with multiple copies of the counter array to reduce dependencies, and sum at the end (with SIMD).  Putting multiple counters in the same memory "bin" is the opposite.  (And if you don't need counts, pure stores with only write-after-write dependencies are a lot easier to for the store-buffer to handle.)